# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, firefox

In [Lattice Diamond](http://www.latticesemi.com/latticediamond) I receive the following message in the terminal:

```
/usr/local/diamond/3.10_x64/bin/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
/usr/local/diamond/3.10_x64/bin/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

in order to open a html file from the "help" menu.

my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty, and the missing library is installed on my system:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

so I added it to my library path and restarted the application. It did not help:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Comment: I completely rephrased the question, as it seems the issue is specific to a certain application and not necessarily a global system configuration. I launched the application from the command line and received an error message.

Comment: @DavidFoerster this fixed the problem, it is working now. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidFoerster, it fixed the problem for Diamond, but is causing problems for another application. Is there a way to apply the fix per working environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the libstdc++ provided with the application is too old for some other, non-provided libraries. You can replace it with a symbolic link to the system’s `libstdc++` (while backing up the original file):

```
sudo ln --backup=simple --suffix=.orig -sft /usr/local/diamond/3.10_x64/bin/lin64 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: this is working fine with Lattice Diamond, but now I can no longer launch docnav from Xilinx: 
```
docnav
QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Connection refused
```

Comment: @TheUltimateSource: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.